# Expecting HTMLImageElement but getting simple Object when iterating over jQuery list of img tags

Tags: jquery

I am gather imgs:

```
container.find('img')
```

Log says this is (console.log('img '+imgs[0]))

> [object HTMLImageElement]

But when I iterating over this list with each():

```
            container.find('img').each(function(idx) {
                var curr = $(this);
                                    console.log('curr ' + curr);

        });
```

I am getting:

> [object Object]

I think it is reason of my anotger problem of checking existance in array:

```
        if (! jQuery.inArray(curr, hiddenImgs)) {
              hiddenImgs.push(curr);
            }
```

And even that I am sure that element is no in array I am getting FALSE :/

It's crazy. Could someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, to get useful log result, just log it directly instead of converting it to a string:

Examples:

```
console.log( imgs[0] );
console.log( curr );
```

Secondly, in the first case you are logging the Image element and in the second case you are logging a jQuery object:

```
$(this) //<-- return a jQuery object wrapping `this`, the original element is in $(this)[0]
this //<-- plain this, it's the dom element itself. I.E. HTMLImageElement
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting **[object Object]** because when you called `$(this)` in your function, you created a new jQuery object that references the image element, and the type of a jquery object is an **object** and not **HTMLImageElement**.
See [jQuery( selector [, context] )](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1)

The function `inArray` returns **-1** and not **0** when it doesn't find a match, so you have to change your code to:

```
if (jQuery.inArray(curr, hiddenImgs) == -1) {
              hiddenImgs.push(curr);
            }
```

See [jQuery.inArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

Answer (score 0):

inside the `.each()` try:

`console.log('curr ' + curr.get(0));`